# Execute a .map() function every 'x' amount of seconds

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
function getPattern (sequence) {
  sequence.map(pod => pod.classList.add('playing'))
  // rest of code
}
```

How would I execute `pod.classList.add('playing')` every, let's say, 2 seconds? Moreover, I want to keep this synchronous to ensure that `//rest of code` is run after all the `pod` iterations have finished.

(For those wondering, sequence is just an array of HTML nodes)

**EDIT** What I have tried:

```
sequence.forEach(pod => setTimeout(() => { pod.classList.add('playing') }, 2000))
sequence.map(pod => setTimeout(() => { pod.classList.add('playing') }, 2000))

setTimeout(() => {
 sequence.map(pod => pod.classList.add('playing'))
}, 2000)
setInterval(() => {
 sequence.map(pod => pod.classList.add('playing'))
}, 2000)
```

However I am suffering both problems I wanted to avoid in the question:
`addClass` isn't delayed; all iterations execute 'at the same time'. Moreover, the `// rest of code`  is being run asynchronously (a.k.a I am noticing `console.log`'s immediately).

Comment: `setInterval(function(){ getPattern(); }, 1000); // every 1 seconds` ?

Comment: That's not how `map` works. `map` returns a new array. You probably want `forEach`.

Comment: Duly noted. Still suffering the same problem, though (as shown in the edit). @Andy

Comment: Are you wanting to set an item's class then wait to add the class to the next item? Or are you wanting to iterate through the whole array each time?

Comment: Whatever youre doing, setTimeout is probably a workaround. If there are pods added, simply pass them through a function that adds the class. And by the way, your code is fully working

Comment: @JasonAllan Add class to array[0], wait 2 seconds... Add class to array[1], wait 2 seconds... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Promise`s to spread out adding the class to each node and also to run code after all nodes have been processed.

```js
var myArrayOfDomNodes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p'));

addClassesSequentially(myArrayOfDomNodes).then(_ => {
    // this code will run after all classes have been added.
    console.log('all done');
});

function addClassAfterTwoSeconds(el) {
    return new Promise(res => {
        setTimeout(_ => {
            el.classList.add('playing');
            res();
        }, 2000);
    });
}

function addClassesSequentially(sequence) {
    let item = sequence.shift();
    return item ? addClassAfterTwoSeconds(item).then(addClassesSequentially.bind(null, sequence)) : Promise.resolve();
}
```

```css
p.playing {
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<p>Three</p>
<p>Four</p>
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. However I am just struggling to understand the ternary operator. How does item become false, resulting in a resolved promise?

Comment: @JamesBarrett, it's not ever actually `false`, just "falsy".  On the last recursion, `sequence` will be an empty array, and thus `sequence.shift()` will produce the value `undefined`.  `undefined` will trigger the false path of the ternary, because `undefined` coerces to `false` (i.e. `Boolean(undefined) === false`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply pause your script's execution, using `setTimeout`/`setInterval` is your only option.
However since all `setTimeout` calls get executed the same time, you either have to nest them or call them with increasing timeouts (2s, 4s, 6s, ...).
The latter can be achieved by calling the following:

```
`sequence.forEach((pod, i) => setTimeout(() => { pod.classList.add('playing') }, (i + 1) * 2000))`
```

For execution the rest of the script after the last callback has finished, you have to wrap it in another `setTimeout` callback with a delay of `sequence.length * 2000` (or `(sequence.length + 1) * 2000`, depending on your needs).